# Using a Regex to clean string versus Base64 Encoded string

Tags: c#, regex, base64

I have a extension method that is using a `Regex.Replace` to clean up invalid characters in an user-entered string before it is added to a XML document.

The intent of the regex is to strip out some random hi-ASCII characters that are occasionally in the input when the user pastes text from Microsoft Word and replace them with a space:

```
    public static string CleanInput(this string inputString) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString))
            return string.Empty;

        // Replace invalid characters with a space.
        return Regex.Replace(inputString, @"[^\w\.@-]", " ");
    }
```

Now as fate would have it, someone is now using this extension method on a string that contains base64-encoded data.

What I believe is that the regex will leave *MOST* of the base64 data unmodified, however I think it is might be changing some of it.

So - knowing that `\w` in the regex is matching `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and that Base64 effectively the same range, *should* this regex be changing the string or not?

If it is changing the string, why and how would you change it so that hi-ASCII garbage is still cleaned up in regular non-encoded text without mucking up the encoded string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 also uses `+`,`/`, and `=`.

You can add these to your character class:

```
[^\w\.@+/=-]
```

Note that `-` has to be last in order for it to be a literal hyphen-minus instead of specifying a range.

It may also be worth considering that `\w` isn't necessarily the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]` [according to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: As I know @ and - characters are not possible in Base64. And the = sign can only be at the end of the endcoded string (to fill the length of the string so it will be a multiple of 4), so maybe this only character could be tested separately as end-of-string character(s): `(=+)$`